# How to speed up league Filesystem?

Tags: php, azure, performance, filesystems, azure-blob-storage

Actually I'm using this API https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/v1/docs/

The local adapter is fine but Azure adapter takes 25+ secs to load the directory lists!!!

Can anyone help me to minimize the list load time somehow? thanks

```
use League\Flysystem\AzureBlobStorage\AzureBlobStorageAdapter;
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\BlobRestProxy;

include __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = BlobRestProxy::createBlobService('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME};AccountKey={YOUR_ACCOUNT_KEY};');
$adapter = new AzureBlobStorageAdapter($client, 'container_name');
$filesystem = new Filesystem($adapter);
var_dump($filesystem->listContents());
```

Comment: I don't know, why I got downvoted. Please comment here!

Comment: I would think due to one of two reasons, either the person didn't understand your question or there is no way to help you out with this. But I think your question is legit. But i think it might be hard to help you with it, if an adapter created by someone else is slow then it is slow.

Comment: I will up vote it for you.

Comment: @DanielBjörk Thanks bro, you are right. I can modify my question or whatever the case, at least it's not duplicate. I was looking for some suggestion like to use cache or any alternative, especially who already used this and learn from his/her experience.